# Static Content on Development and Production Envoirnment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, static

I am using Asp.Net MVC 2 to build the web application. The question is regarding the static content. In the production, the static content is residing at sub domain http://static.jobsora.com/content/css/. While, in development it is residing at the default location of ../Content/css/. Example:

For Production:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://static.jobsora.com/Content/css/search-min.css" />
```

For Development:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/css/search-min.css") %>" />
```

I know change of codebase for production is not at all an approach. So, I am looking for better approach. I think this can be trick down by Absolute URL, but how? No idea!

Thanks.

Comment: May I ask why changing of the codebase is not an option?

Comment: I think he means changing it so it works in production and not dev, or changing some of the code only the production server

Comment: @alexn Good question. Let suppose, I need to do deployment, first on QA server, then on Build Server, then on Production server. You can easily figure out how many times I need to change code-base. Another point, QA never allow me to change even a single line of code after QA verification and frankly this is not a single line of code.

Comment: @Daniel Powell Yes, somehow, what I required.

Comment: Don't you have a build script which can handle this for you?

Comment: Ok, that would be my recommended solution. Create a buildscript which compiles your solution and copies needed files. You can then use a bat file and choose which environment you want to compile to. I recommend reading http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Building-a-StackOverflow-inspired-Knowledge-Exchange-Build-automation-with-NAnt.aspx. I can also recommend Phantom instead of NAnt.

Comment: This build script can then replace your link depending on environment.

Answer (score 1):

Consider programmably adding links to the page by adding link elements to the head.  It can be done from code-behind, and you could work around it that way using:

```
#if DEBUG

#else

#endif
```

Or some other construct.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom helper like this:

```
public static class HtmlHelpers
{
    public static MvcHtmlString Css(this HtmlHelper helper, string fileName)
    {
        string folder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StaticContent"];
        fileName += (fileName.EndsWith(".css") == true) ? "" : ".css";
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(string.Format(@"<link rel=""stylesheet"" type=""text/css"" href=""{0}/{1}"" />", folder, helper.AttributeEncode(fileName)));
    }
}
```

Then in your View all you need is:

```
@Html.Css("search-min.css")
```

Then you could use web.config transformation to set the value for development and production. You can find information here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx.