# how to get URL path on local host and on server?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5

Plase guide me how to get URL path **excluding** page name on localhost and server.

for example for the page Active.aspx local path that I want to get is here in bold.

***http://localhost:1532/WebFolder/***Active.aspx

and on server I want to get this bold part

****http://domain.com/WebFolder/****Active.aspx

Similarly if page is in root it will return

****http://domain.com/****Active.aspx or* *http://localhost:1532/**Active.aspx

Comment: some suggestions here might help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544096/static-content-on-development-and-production-envoirnment

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Request.ApplicationPath` - Gets the ASP.NET application's virtual application root path on the server.

`Request.Path` - Gets the virtual path of the current request.

**Edit**

To get domain + current request + virtual path of the current application, try below:

```
Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Request.ApplicationPath
```

Comment: @user576510 - try second option

Comment: Works great.  I was calling a page inside an iFrame for testing on my development machine and it uses LocalHost then some random port number that I didn't want to hard-code.  Applying your suggestion like this: Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Page.ResolveUrl("TestHttpMethods.aspx")  did the trick and gave me this: "http://localhost:62053/Pages/Forms/TestHttpMethods.aspx".  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Request.Url.AbsoluteUri is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

Use this. Its working

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + "/" + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath + "/" + folderpath + filename;

Answer (score 0):

You can use Request.servervariable["Remote_addr"] to get the ip address.But if you try on local host, it will returns default ip address of your machine. You can check this code from web server, can get ip address.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the local file path of a page, eg. "Active.aspx"
Use

```
Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath
```

which ignores your localhost, local host file mapping, or virtual directory name and will return "**~/Active.aspx**"
Other properties such as Request.Url.LocalPath won't help.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
Server.MapPath("~/");
       or 
Request.Url.Host
```